# Why does the KendoUI Grid not rollback a delete when the options.error function is called?

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-grid

I have put a fiddle here that demonstrates the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/fmzay/1/

Just delete a record, and it should rollback the delete as I am calling options.error from inside the destroy function.

Why is it that the grid doesn't roll back?

Regards,

Scott

Markup:

```
<div id="KendoGrid"></div>
```

JS:

```
var _data = [
        { Users_ID: 1, Users_FullName: 'Bob Smith', Users_Role: 'Administrator'  },
        { Users_ID: 2, Users_FullName: 'Barry Baker', Users_Role: 'Viewer'  },
        { Users_ID: 3, Users_FullName: 'Bill Cow', Users_Role: 'Editor'  },
        { Users_ID: 4, Users_FullName: 'Boris Brick', Users_Role: 'Administrator'  }
    ],
    _dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
        data: _data,
        destroy: function (options) {
            options.error(new Error('Error Deleting User'));
        }
    });

$('#KendoGrid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: _dataSource,
    columns: [
        { field: "Users_FullName", title: "Full Name" },
        { field: "Users_Role", title: "Role", width: "130px" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "180px" }
    ],
    toolbar: ['create'],
    editable: 'popup'
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `destroy` function is being called?

Comment: Good call.  Ok I have revised it, and now it gets called.  But still the same behavior, no rollback, and also if you delete more than one record, the destroy event get's raised too many times... 
http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/fmzay/2/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Signaling the error is not enough. Lets say that having an error on removing a record is not enough since KendoUI doesn't know if the record has actually been removed in the server and the reply is the one producing the error. So KendoUI approach is a conservative approach: You have to decide what to do and explicitly say it:

So what you should do is add an [`error`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-error) hander function that invokes a [`cancelChanges`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-cancelChanges) in the grid.

The code would be:

```
_dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            options.success(_data);
            console.log('Read Event Has Been Raised');
        },
        destroy: function (options) {
            options.error(new Error('Error Deleting User'));
            console.log('Destroy Event Has Been Raised');
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Users_ID",
            fields: {
                Users_ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Users_FullName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                Users_Role: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(a) {
        $('#KendoGrid').data("kendoGrid").cancelChanges();
    }
});
```

And the updated JSFiddle in here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/fmzay/3

Comment: Fantastic mate.  Now how come the Destroy event get's raised so many times... Every time I press the Delete button, it gets raised one more time.  Have a look at the console to see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/fmzay/5/

Comment: That was actually a bug on that release. If you check with latest you will see that it works http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/fmzay/6/

Comment: Ahhh, yes I must have forked this from an old fiddle to begin with.  That is great.  Once again thank you for the support. Much appreciated!!

Comment: No need for selecting the kendoGrid. The reference is there:  this.cancelChanges();

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.NET-MVC equivalent solution to the OnaBai answer would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cancelChanges(e) {
    e.sender.cancelChanges();
}
</script>

@Html.Kendo().Grid<MyClass>()
.DataSource(dataSource =>
    dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "MyController"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "MyController"))
    .Events(evt => evt.Error("cancelChanges"))
)
[...]
```

Please be aware that the *cancelChanges* event will be called upon an error on every CRUD request.

Comment: Nice. It's better to use "e.sender" than getting a reference to the grid using jquery like in the accepted answer.

Comment: @AugustoBarreto: `e.sender` would refer to the dataSource, not the grid. The grid would be at `e.sender.options.table.parent('div')[0]` which doesn't look much better ;)

Comment: @mrmashal Right. Thanks!